# React Native Navigation Custom Border

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I am a beginner in React Native. I want to configure the **React Navigation 5.x** with custom style. And I am unable to trim border-bottom like following. Please help me with This.

[Custom Style for React Navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmqIR.jpg)

**My Current Code:**

```
function StackNavigator() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator
                screenOptions={{
                    headerStyle: styles.header,
                    headerBackImage: () => (
                        <Image
                            style={styles.headerBack}
                            source={require("../assets/icons/64x/chevron-left.png")}
                        />
                    ),
                    headerLeftContainerStyle: {
                        alignItems: "flex-start",
                        paddingHorizontal: theme.sizes.padding / 2
                    },
                    headerTitleStyle: styles.headerTitle
                }}
            >
                <Stack.Screen
                    name="Login"
                    component={LoginScreen}
                    options={{ headerShown: true }}
                />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    header: {
        height: theme.sizes.base * 5,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        borderWidth: 0,
        elevation: 0,
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderBottomColor: Colors.grayLight
    },
    headerBack: {
        height: 20,
        width: 20
    },
    headerTitle: {
        fontSize: 18,
        fontFamily: "Quicksand",
        letterSpacing: -1
    }
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried right clicking and using inspect element?

It should tell you which css class is being used to generate that UI. Many times imported components import their own css classes which you have to override to change the look and feel.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this style to the `cardStyle` property of the `screenOptions`:

```js
function StackNavigator() {
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
                cardStyle : { backgroundColor : 'lightgray', margin : 15 },
                headerStyle: styles.header,
                headerBackImage: () => (
                    <Image
                        style={styles.headerBack}
                        source={require("../assets/icons/64x/chevron-left.png")}
                    />
                ),
                headerLeftContainerStyle: {
                    alignItems: "flex-start",
                    paddingHorizontal: theme.sizes.padding / 2
                },
                headerTitleStyle: styles.headerTitle
            }}
        >
            <Stack.Screen
                name="Login"
                component={LoginScreen}
                options={{ headerShown: true }}
            />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
}
```

Which will produce something like this:

[image: Screenshot of iOS simulator]

Comment: Do you know how you would wrap the entire app like above, with the header if a header for each screen is present?